# Change only state of clicked card

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, react-state

How can I get the clicked card only to change its string from 'not captured' to 'captured'? Right now, all cards' strings say 'captured' even if I click on only one. I think the problem is that the captured state updates for all the cards and I can't get the captured state to update for the single clicked card. It's an onChange event and a checkbox.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import PokemonCard from '../components/PokemonCard';


const Pokedex = () => {
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    const [captured, setCaptured] = useState(false )
    const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151';

    const fetchingPokemons = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(URL);
        const data = await res.json();
        // console.log(data)
        setPokemons(data.results)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchingPokemons()
    }, [URL])

    const toggleCaptured= (e, id) => {
        console.log(id)

        if(id && e) {
            console.log('oh')
            setCaptured(captured => !captured)
        }

        let capturedPkm = [];
        let notCapturedPkm = [];

        pokemons.forEach(i => {
            if(captured === true) {
                capturedPkm.push(pokemons[i])
            } else {
                notCapturedPkm.push(pokemons[i])
            }
        })
        console.log('captured', capturedPkm, 'not captured', notCapturedPkm)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
                {pokemons ? pokemons.map((pokemon) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <div style={{ width: '235px'  }} >
                                <PokemonCard
                                    pokemon={pokemon}
                                    name={pokemon.name}
                                    url={pokemon.url}
                                    key={pokemon.id}
                                    captured={captured}
                                    toggleCaptured={toggleCaptured}
                                />

                            </div>

                        </>
                    )
                }) : <h1>Loading...</h1>}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Pokedex

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PokemonIcon from './PokemonIcon';

const PokemonCard = (props) => {
    const { url, captured, toggleCaptured } = props

    const URL = url

    const [pokemonCard, setPokemonCard] = useState([])

    const fetchingPokemonCard = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(URL);
        const data = await res.json();
        //console.log(data)
        setPokemonCard(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchingPokemonCard()
    }, [URL])

    return (
        <>
            <div className='pokemon-card' style={{
                height: '250px',
                maxWidth: '250px',
                margin: '1rem',
                boxShadow: '5px 5px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
            }} >
                <Link
                to={{ pathname: `/pokemon/${pokemonCard.id}` }}
                state={{ pokemon: pokemonCard, captured }}
                style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000000' }}>
                    <div
                    style={{ padding: '20px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} >
                        <PokemonIcon img={pokemonCard.sprites?.['front_default']} />
                    </div>
                </Link>
                <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <h1 >{pokemonCard.name}</h1>
                    <label >
                        <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            defaultChecked= {captured}
                            onChange={(e) => toggleCaptured(e.target.checked, pokemonCard.id)}
                        />
                        <span style={{ marginLeft: 8, cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                            {captured === false ? 'Not captured!' : 'Captured!'}
                            {console.log(captured)}
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default PokemonCard
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object as state:

```
const [captured, setCaptured] = useState({})
```

Set the toggle function:

```
const toggleCaptured = (checked, id) => {
  const currentChecked = { ...captured }; // Create a shallow copy
  console.log(id)
  if (checked) {
    currentChecked[id] = true;
  } else {
    delete currentChecked[id];
  }
  setCaptured(currentChecked); // Update the state
  
  let capturedPkm = pokemons.filter(({id}) => currentChecked[id]);
  let notCapturedPkm = pokemons.filter(({id}) => !currentChecked[id]);

  console.log('captured', capturedPkm, 'not captured', notCapturedPkm)
}
```

The PokemonCard should look like this

```js
<PokemonCard
  pokemon={pokemon}
  name={pokemon.name}
  url={pokemon.url}
  key={pokemon.id}
  captured={captured[pokemon.id]} // Here
  toggleCaptured={toggleCaptured}
/>
```

Comment: HI @joseluismurillorios ! Thanks for your reply. If I use your code as you've written it, captured is undefined in the Pokedex component. What am I missing? I've realised that I don't have a pokemon.id in Pokedex but I do have it in the PokemonCard. In PokemonCard I can't reach all the pokemons though... ouch.